# Why do I get the "No operations defined in spec!" message when accessing Swagger documentation for my app?

Tags: node.js, express, swagger, swagger-ui, swagger-jsdocs

so I'm trying to set up Swagger for my NodeJS app but I'm struggling with a problem for a while now. I will try to explain as detailed as possible.

So I have swagger.util.js file:

```
import swaggerJSDoc from "swagger-jsdoc";

const options = {
    failOnErrors: true,
    definition: {
        openapi: "3.0.0",
        info: {
            title: "API",
            version: "1.0.0",
            description: "Endpoints"
        },
        servers: [
            {
                url: "http://localhost:80",
                description: "HTTP"
            },
            {
                url: "http://localhost:443",
                description: "HTTPS"
            }
        ],
    },
    apis: ["../routes/*.js"]
};

const specs = swaggerJSDoc(options);

export default specs;
```

This user.route.js file:

```
import express from "express";
import trimRequest from "trim-request";

import { register } from "../controllers/user.controller.js";

const router = express.Router();

/**
 * @swagger
 * components:
 *   schemas:
 *     UserAccount:
 *       type: object
 *       required:
 *         - username
 *         - email
 *         - password
 *       properties:
 *         username:
 *           type: string
 *         email:
 *           type: string
 *         password:
 *           type: string
 *       example:
 *         username: Test
 *         email: test@test.com
 *         password: TestTest1!
 */
router.route("/register").post(trimRequest.all, register);

export default router;
```

And this app.js file that is used in index.js:

```
import compression from "compression";
import cookieParser from "cookie-parser";
import cors from "cors";
import dotenv from "dotenv";
import express from "express";
import mongoSanitize from "express-mongo-sanitize";
import helmet from "helmet";
import createHttpError from "http-errors";
import morgan from "morgan";
import swaggerUI from "swagger-ui-express";

import routes from "./routes/index.route.js";
import specs from "./utils/swagger.utils.js";

dotenv.config();

const app = express();

app.use(compression());
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}));
app.use(helmet());
app.use(mongoSanitize());
if (process.env.ENV !== "prd") {
    app.use(morgan("dev"));
}
app.use("/docs", swaggerUI.serve, swaggerUI.setup(specs));
console.log(specs);

// Remove this later
app.get("/", (_req, res) => {
    res.send("Hello");
});

app.use("/api/v1", routes);

app.use(async (_req, __res, next) => {
    next(createHttpError.NotFound("This route does not exist"));
});

app.use(async (err, _req, res,_next) => {
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    res.send({
        error: {
            status: err.status || 500,
            message: err.message,
        },
    });
});

export default app;
```

The folder structure is the following:

```
-src
 -controllers
  -user.controller.js
 -routes
  -index.route.js
  -user.route.js
 -utils
  -swagger.utils.js
 -app.js
 -index.js
```

The problem is that console.log(specs); from app.js returns a json that has the components field empty (empty object) for some reason. But it should return something since I have that JSDoc comment in the user.route.js right?
[image: console]

And as I said, the doc is empty too:

[image: doc]


Do you know which might be the cause/problem? Or how can I fix this? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your issue is where you run the command from. If you're running the command from the root of the project, your relative path is incorrect.

```js
const options = {
    definition: {

        openapi: '3.0.3',
        info: {
            title: 'test',
            version: '1.0.0'
        },
        servers: [
            { url: 'https://www.example.com/v1' }
        ]
    },
    apis: [
        'src/routes/user.route.js'  // <<< this can't use a relative ref. 
    ]
}
```

Here's a simple repo

```
src
 ┣ routes
 ┃ ┗ user.route.js
 ┣ utils
 ┃ ┗ openapi.util.js
 ┗ index.js
```

```js
// index.js
import express from 'express'
import swaggerUI from 'swagger-ui-express'
import OASdescription from './utils/openapi.util.js'

const app = express()
app.use(express.json())
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000

app.use('/api/docs', swaggerUI.serve, swaggerUI.setup(OASdescription))

app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`listening on port ${PORT}`))
```

```js
// openapi.util.js
import swaggerJsdoc from 'swagger-jsdoc'

const options = {
    definition: {

        openapi: '3.0.3',
        info: {
            title: 'test',
            version: '1.0.0'
        },
        servers: [
            { url: 'https://www.example.com/v1' }
        ]
    },
    apis: [
        'src/routes/user.route.js'
    ]
}

const OASDescription = swaggerJsdoc(options)

export default OASDescription
```

```js
// user.route.js
import { Router } from 'express'

const router = Router()

/**
* @openapi
* '/user':
*   get:
*     description: my hosted api docs
*     summary: api docs
*     responses:
*       '200':
*         description: OK
*         content:
*           'application/json':
*             schema:
*               type: object
*               properties:
*                 thing:
*                   $ref: '#/components/schemas/UserAccount'
* components:
*   schemas:
*     UserAccount:
*       type: object
*       required:
*         - username
*       properties:
*         username:
*           type: string
*/
router.get('/user', (req, res) => {

    res.status('200').json({ "username": "test" })
})

export default router
```

[image: swagger]

Comment: Yes, indeed that relative path was the problem. It works with "src/routes/user.route.js". Thank you so much!